# Digitally signed SOAP in ColdFusion with WebLogic

Tags: soap, coldfusion, weblogic

For a project I am working on I need to create a digitally signed SOAP request in ColdFusion 8. I was recommended to use [Apache WSS4J](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/), but was told by the platform manager that the server runs on WebLogic not Apache. Is it possible to use WebLogic to digitally sign a SOAP request in ColdFusion?

Comment: This might be better suited for ServerFault

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked at other similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598338/sign-jax-ws-soap-request

Comment: Yes, there are many questions relating to Signing SOAPs but almost nothing relating to using coldfusion, and those that do relate to CF use Apache