# convert X509 certificate tag value to base64 binary encoding in digital signature cxf wss4j

Tags: java, soap, cxf, digital-signature, wss4j

I have used **CXF 3.0.1** for soap implementation and for digital signature I have used **wss4j-WS-security-common 3.0.1** and **CXF-rt-WS-security 3.0.1**. By adding outinterceptor in non-spring settings and along with crypto.merlin properties, I do the digital signature.
Now according to the output that is obtained, my webservice provider asks for  a **BASE64** binary value of **X509Data** tag.
To Summarize I want to replace this:

```xml
<ds:KeyInfo Id="...">
  <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="...">
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          <ds:X509IssuerName>C=...,O=...,CN=....</ds:X509IssuerName>
          <ds:X509SerialNumber>70391139840......</ds:X509SerialNumber>
        </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
      </ds:X509Data>
   </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

With this one:

```xml
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>MIIE4zCCA8ugAwIBAgI...</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
```

My current complete output is:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            soap:mustUnderstand="true">
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                Id="SIG-0ce2ba1e-9382-4b99-918f-40fe35c0bcd6">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                            PrefixList="soap"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-f2a96bde-6b41-4283-9fcd-703eca4fd795">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces
                                    xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                    PrefixList=""/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>nIHemuhLTu4c/drCPaK1is/.....</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    R3Of2Bf60qeSHFyUf5Op7TCGIwJWnhuyHWTNUxNRNLzye6Qi0YeVXTwb0WF9Nesizs16Y...
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-38c8124d-967f-4075-99c3-dca94b7d15e9">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-9defa6fa-794a-40a3-a57d-2bb1335cbfb6">
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>C=...,O=...,CN=....</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>70391139840......</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>
```

output that I want to be shown:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap:Header>
        <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <UserName>*</UserName>
          <Password>*</Password>
        </AuthHeader>
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        ...
      </soap:Body>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
          <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>yPt/HXyJyVi1GFFoBb52sTwpaQscONr6QQ2wW....</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>u+XmtuZRW1pqfnIaExnheNGMgg...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>MIIE4zCCA8ugAwIBAgI...</X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

This is my Java client code:

```java
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client =ClientProxy.getClient(ServicesSoap);
 client.getOutInterceptors().add(new SAAJOutInterceptor());
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
 Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
 WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
 cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "1");
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE,"crypto.properties");
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, 
 ClientPasswordCallback.class.getName());
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_DIGEST_ALGO, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.MUST_UNDERSTAND, "true");
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_ALGO, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USE_SINGLE_CERTIFICATE, "false");
 outProps.put("SecurityToken", "wsse:Base64Binary");
```

crypto.properties:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=JKS
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=/home/...
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=1
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=...
```

Comment: I am not posting this as an answer because I do not know if this is actually what you need. Probably you can configure the [SIG_KEY_ID](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/ConfigurationConstants.html#SIG_KEY_ID) property to an appropriate value. For example: `outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");`. Try the `X509KeyIdentifier` property value as well. Please, see the [official documentation](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html) or this [blog](http://coheigea.blogspot.com/2013/03/signature-and-encryption-key.html). I hope it helps.

Comment: @KayvanTehrani Mehdi, were you able to test the proposed solution?

Comment: @jccampanero thanks for your suggestion. but this is not our problem. as you can see in the sample codes, we want to change the contents of the X509data tag to the encoding base64 without any changes to the names of tags. In other words, using of SIG_KEY_ID property and the value of "DirectReference" caused to change the names of the tags (keyIdentifier).

Comment: I understand @mehdihoseeini, thank you for the feedback. Then, probably the best approach you can take is to get rid of wss4j, provide a custom CXF interceptor (please, consider read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109111/manually-sign-soap-message-java) extraordinary article from Glen Mazza), and generate the XML Signature directly. Please, see for example the answer provided for Yash in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109111/manually-sign-soap-message-java) SO question. Please, let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched a lot about this problem. two approaches to solve this problem are using Apache CXF-SAML and also if you want to use wss4j, you can send your request to someone who Authorized your certificate with the name of tags that you tell them.